# Getting Xdebug to work with Laravel Sail + PhpStorm

Tags: laravel, phpstorm, xdebug, wsl-2, laravel-sail

I have spent 3 days on this now and I can't figure this out. I am running a project using Laravel Sail on WSL2, I'm using PhpStorm for my IDE and trying to get step debugging with Xdebug working. The project is built from an existing container it's not new, but it is a new computer, no matter what I do I can't get Xdebug working.

I have tried several .env variables, including these currently in the file:

```ini
XDEBUG=true
XDEBUG_MODE=develop,debug
XDEBUG_CONFIG="client_host=host.docker.internal"

SAIL_XDEBUG=true
SAIL_XDEBUG_MODE=develop,debug
SAIL_XDEBUG_CONFIG="client_host=host.docker.internal"
```

My docker compose.yml has:

```yaml
environment:
    WWWUSER: '${WWWUSER}'
    LARAVEL_SAIL: 1
    XDEBUG: '${SAIL_XDEBUG:-false}'
    XDEBUG_PORT: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_PORT:-9003}'
    XDEBUG_MODE: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_MODE:-off}'
    XDEBUG_CONFIG: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_CONFIG:-client_host=host.docker.internal}'
```

and running `./vendor/bin/sail exec laravel.test php -v` shows Xdebug is working

```
PHP 7.4.3-4ubuntu2.19 (cli) (built: Jun 27 2023 15:49:59) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.4.3-4ubuntu2.19, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.9.2, Copyright (c) 2002-2020, by Derick Rethans
```

Even the PhpStorm validator is all ticks.

[image]

But I can set whatever breakpoints I want, even "Break at first line in PHP scripts" and still nothing.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Double check how you are configuring this all. The thing is: 1) `develop,debug` is Xdebug v3 only. 2) `9003` is a default port for Xdebug v3. 3) But the screenshot from PhpStorm shows that it's Xdebug v2 (and v3 params do NOTHING in v2...) **P.S.** PHP 7.4 can use Xdebug v3 (3.0 or maybe 3.1 max, latest is 3.2)... Maybe try installing v3 inside the container?..

Comment: For Xdebug v3 -- execute the test page with calling `xdebug_info()` there -- it will list all live Xdebug params. For v2 -- you have to use `phpinfo()` and check the Xdebug specific section -- what values live params have set...

Comment: Also note that it is possible to have different PHP (version and especially config files) for CLI and web server. Always check what php.ini config files are loaded (the paths) -- maybe you are editing the wrong one etc... It should not be the case here at all... just think it was worth noting it.

Comment: on my prior machine it installed xdebug 3.1.2, now its installing 2.9.2. I'm having no success in changing that either.  my old dockerfile started with FROM ubuntu:21.04 but that build failed, apparently it's not maintained anymore? I can only get it to build with FROM ubuntu:20.04. is this the reason xdebug 2.9.2 is being installed?

Comment: Sorry, cannot advise on those questions -- I'm not using Laravel Sail myself so cannot say what has changed and what needs to be done in this Docker images regard. Better check with Laravel Sail folks.

Comment: In your .env (and maybe your docker-compose.yml) I am missing this directive: `PHP_IDE_CONFIG=serverName=`. There are a bunch of things to set, but let's configure this one first. Then I would set the debug_port on 9003 or 9005. In phpstorm xdebug section (show screendhot) set correct port. Configure servers (screenshot please) and then configure debug itself in the menu option (screenshot please)

Comment: 2 links that gave me some guidance: https://medium.com/codex/laravel-8-0-sail-xdebug-phpstorm-5cc900e96da4 and https://blog.stackademic.com/debugging-laravel-sail-with-xdebug-3-in-phpstorm-2023-a-detailed-guide-84a594c09586

Answer (score 2):

My dockerfile was completely outdated. I don't even know exactly where it was going wrong but I fixed it by creating a completely new laravel sail project, copying the 8.0 docker file, changing everything to 7.4, node to version 18. and the build succeeded, and xdebug 3.1.2 is now installed and working.